# How to align three blocks on the front page using CSS

Tags: theming, blocks, i18n-l10n

I've got three blocks on my front page and I want them to be centered and aligned.

"About us" block is to be aligned to the left side of the front page what I managed to achieve. The other two blocks are to be aligned to the right side of the front page and one above the other what I managed to achieve as well.

However:

1. Different browsers show different results which is caused by the reference of the language switcher block I guess. It is moving my right hand side set of blocks up and down. IE is showing the result I would like to achieve (the example: [test site](http://lhziadwg.preview.infomaniak.com/)).
2. I would like to be able to reference language switcher block to the content region which is not the case right now and I am not sure how to do it.

Can someone help or guide me into the propriate direction?

Thanks and regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after looking at your code I concluded that your css codes are terrible! you may use this code (I didn't test it but it should work or at least a few modifications will make it to perfectly match what you need):

```
<div id="content">
       <div id="blocks-container">
             <div id="left-block">
                    //In here load the slider block and display in here
             </div>
              <div id="right-block">
                     <div>
                    //In here load the top right  block and display in here
                     </div>
                     <div>
                     //In here load the bottom right  block and display in here
                     </div>
             </div>
       </div>
</div>
```

This is CSS

```
#content{
       text-align:center;
       width:100%;
       height:auto;
       display:inline-block;     
}
#blocks-container{
       margin:auto;
       width: 975px;
       height:auto;
       display:inline-block;     
}
#left-block{
       float:left;
       width: 760px;
}
#right-block{
       float:right;
       width: 215px;
}
#right-block > div{
       clear:both;
       width: 100%;
      float:left;  
}
```

Never use margin to align elements to the right, because the margin is calculated based on the parent which in your case is the browser, so If you resize the browser, the browser will try to move the elements to regard the margin.

I recommend you strongly to forget about the `DIV` and `float`, try to learn how to work with [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) it is very easy to use.

Comment: Many thanks dor the answer. Needless to say that I a starter and what I developed is based on what I could learn after I followed few youtube tutorials. Can you just let me know where/hiw I can add divs you suggested?

Comment: How did you start drupal when you know nothing about html/css ?!,Well just remove the `DIV` with `content` id and replace my code in there

Comment: As I've said, I've followed quite few YOUTUBE tutorials and GOOGLED the drupal documentation. This is how I ended up with what I've developed. HTML and CSS, as you could have seen... the basic knowledge hence my question, where/how I should add your suggestion, where exactly (file name) I can replace content DIV with what you suggested? Not sure why I was able to reference "about us" block to the content region and "language switcher" is pointing to the very top of the page?? Why I cannot reference "language switcher" to the content as well? Many thanks again for your help, much appreciated!!!

Comment: Is this how the structure should look like after I implement your suggestion?

div id="content" class="column" role="main">
<a id="main-content"></a>
<div id="blocks-container">
<div id="left-block">
<div id="block-views-about-us-front-page-block" class="block block-views first odd">
</div>
<div id="right-block">
<div id="block-locale-language" class="block block-locale even" role="complementary">
<div id="block-views-customer-feedback-block" class="block block-views last odd">
</div>
</div>

Comment: You need to write that code in `page--front.tpl.php` of your theme

Comment: Hmm, I am not sure how to do it, this is the CONTENT div of my page--front.tpl.php:

`<div id="content" class="column" role="main">
   <?php print render($page['highlighted']); ?>
   <?php print $breadcrumb; ?>
   <a id="main-content"></a>
   <?php print $messages; ?>
   <?php print render($tabs); ?>
   <?php print render($page['help']); ?>
   <?php if ($action_links): ?>
   <ul class="action-links"><?php print render($action_links); ?></ul>
   <?php endif; ?>
   <?php print render($page['content']); ?>
   <?php print $feed_icons; ?>
 </div>`

Comment: If I look into the structure via FireBUG it looks different, I can see the content DIV and three other DIVs:

`div id="content" class="column" role="main"> <a id="main-content"></a> <div id="blocks-container"> <div id="left-block"> <div id="block-views-about-us-front-page-block" class="block block-views first odd"> </div> <div id="right-block"> <div id="block-locale-language" class="block block-locale even" role="complementary"> <div id="block-views-customer-feedback-block" class="block block-views last odd"> </div> </div>`

Not sure how to get to what you are saying?

Comment: Why don't you define two regions, `leftRegion` and `rightRegion`, and assign the correspondent blocks in there?

Comment: That would be fine and it would fit to what I need. Wouldn't the regions be one above the other? How to get them one next to the other... in parallel?
CSS I guess? 

Thank you very much for trying to help... despite my limited knowledge!

Comment: Vertical blocks need only one region, for example the blocks that are resided in the right column need only one region, you assign blocks in there and they all will be on top of each other like a stack

Comment: Mate... thank you very much for the time spent with the problem I have experienced. This is at least kind and with best intention to help.
Messing up further with the already bad structure of what I have developed is I'd guess pretty bad idea. Let's not think of getting this structure "mobilized"!!!!
Thank you again, but it didn't get through.

Best regards

Comment: This thing stopped me from completing the sentence... I think I'll stick to the standard without changind the front page width etc... 

Thanks and all the best of the luck

Nebojsa Kuzmanovic

Comment: ;) You welcome  ;)